# Way to know what Windows service pack version is from the browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to find what service pack is installed from the browser? It doesn't look like it's in the System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities in asp.net. I need a way to warn users that they need to update to XP Service Pack 3 before proceeding and installing some software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. Unless it's in the browser's UA, there's no way of detecting it without some kind of plugin.

Comment: I didn't think so, but wanted to double check. Any good solutions already out there?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **VBSCRIPT** you can get what you are looking for.

The WMI class Win32_OperatingSystem has the properties ServicePackMajorVersion, ServicePackMinorVersion, Name and Version.

Try samples here: [WMI Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394596%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Hope this can help

Comment: Only works in IE... And I somehow doubt a VBS running in the "Internet" context has access to that.

Comment: Of course, but if you notice my answer start with <if you can...>, so due the security limitation in a browser you cannot access to local data. Even with a flash as `flash.system.Capabilities` have a look here:
[list of flash.system.Capabilities](http://snipplr.com/view/31781/as3-flashsystemcapabilities-properties/)